# C++: How to create getters/setters for a pointer to a pointer to an array of 3 doubles

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a question of how to return a pointer to a pointer to an array of 3 doubles. In my example, I have a class that has as private member:

```
class MyColorClass {
....
    private:
    const double (**colorData)[3];
...
}
```

How should I write the getter and the setter for this?

This does not work:

```
const double *** MyColorClass::getcolorData()
{
    return colorData;
}
```

PS: I apologize for a previous badly written similar question (I deleted it)

Thank you :)

Comment: Whats the meaning of "This does not work"  when your code is about a compiler error you should include the compiler error message in the question

Comment: why dont you want to use `std::array` ?

Comment: If you have at least C++14 you can just do `const auto getColorData() {...}`

Comment: how did you end up with a pointer to pointer (to whatever) in the first place. You are only a tiny step away from becoming a [three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: Note: Deleted questions are still used in the server's computation of when you can ask your next question. Deleting a question often turns it into an iceberg, the danger hidden from sight until you receive a question ban. It is best to fix the question rather than ask a new one. Of your visible questions, you have a total score of zero and 9 questions. I can't see the deleted questions, so I can't tell how close you are to a ban, but be *very* careful with your next few questions because you're close to being banned just based on what I can see.

Comment: @user4581301 interesting. Afaik users are encouraged to open a new question by the system when their question is closed. If I am not mistaken and you are right, this is a little odd.

Comment: Why would you want `const double (**colorData)[3];` in the first place?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The system should warn and/or rate-limit them before the ban.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: yes indeed, I created a new question after my previous one was badly written. Thanks user4581301, I will check out my stackoverflow status, but what I want to say here is that it's a bit weird when the super AI stakoverflow algorithm does not make a discrimination between a spammer and a poor user. There are a lot of political projections to be said on this design decision

Comment: The logic is likely too static to be considered AI. I suspect it'll be a simple threshold trigger with a small amount of constant weighting on the inputs. I doubt it learns; instead someone most likely manually juggles the weights every now and then when some statistical analysis shows the need for a change. The thinking appears to be along the lines of, "We gave you 8-10 chances to get it right. You didn't. Buh-bye." It's also not just filtering spam. Questions that are poorly composed, obvious duplicates, or otherwise unlikely to be useful to other askers in the future are also noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const double (**getColorData() const)[3]
{
    return colorData;
}
```

The `const` on the right isn't specific to this type, and should be added to all getters. Normally it's on the very right of the declaration, but not in this case.

Replacing array with pointer like you did only makes sense if you're making a getter for an array, but `colorData` is a pointer, not an array (doesn't matter what it's a pointer to).

---

```
                getColorData              // getColorData is
                getColorData() const      // a const function, returning
               *getColorData() const      // a pointer to
              **getColorData() const      // a pointer to
             (**getColorData() const)     // ...
             (**getColorData() const)[3]  // an array of 3 of
const double (**getColorData() const)[3]  // const double
```

Comment: its one of those weird things that I love to see translated to plain english https://cdecl.org/?q=const+double+%28**getColorData%28%29%29%5B3%5D%3B (had to remove the last `const` though)

Comment: and for the [lolz](https://cdecl.org/?q=declare+foo+as+function+returning+pointer+to+pointer+to+array+3+of+const+double)

Comment: Use the freakin' typedef!

Comment: @n.m. Educational purposes, and all that. :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: thanks a lot for your answer, I had never met this syntax before (as many other things in c++). Your answer helped me to open a new space for C++ study.

Comment: @fatecasino beware, there are many dark corners where you can easily get lost. One doesn't need to go everywhere. For many things its good to know it exists, but its so rare you actually need to use it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thanks! I laughed so much with the three star programmer!!!

Comment: @fatecasino its written to be funny, but it is about a serious problem.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: yeah I know, I try my best to increase my understanding